Wolfram Alpha giving wrong answer for critical points
I am trying to find the critical points of the following function
$$ f(x) = \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x^3} $$
I found it manually as $x = 0, 1/3$. Now, I wanted to see what Wolfram Alpha tells. I got the following result.

Now the domain of the function is $ [0, \infty]$. So, it should not give the value $-1/3$ as the critical point. So, is this a bug on their site ?

Wolfram Alpha is assuming a complex-valued square root. If you ask it to solve $\sqrt{x} - 3\sqrt{x^3} = 0$ without any additional assumptions, it will say that $-1/3$ is a root if complex-valued sqrt is assumed.
If you ask it to solve the same equation over the reals, it will give only 0 and 1/3.
This isn't really a bug as much as it is a limitation of the engine to correctly predict what it is that you want.
